# C# Deserialization problem into new class structure

Tags: c#, serialization

I have a class and serialized into XML on hard disk.
Then I add one new parameter into that class.
Can I still able be de-serialize from old xml into new class structure by default de-serializer?

Any things else might affect serialization? 
Rename parameters ?
Delete parameters ?

Comment: Almost Duplicate of this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/618306/best-practice-to-serialize-and-deserialize-net-objects-across-versions

Comment: I agree, there are enough pointers in the different answers to that question to answer this.

Comment: I suggest you try a few things. The XML deserializer does allow some modifications to the classes, and with the available attributes, you can map properties to a different XML element.

Answer (score 2):

I will assume by parameters you are referring to instance variables.

XMLSerializer will just put back the data it can find. Even if you removed (or renamed) a variable it will still be happy.

If however you are saying that you have added a parameter to the constructor just be aware that XMLSerializer requires a parameterless constructor.